# How can I use stackoverflow style markup on my blog posts?

Tags: formatting, markdown, markup, prettify

I've gotten really used to the features StackOverflow provides while writing technical posts. My favorite features are the

```
4 spaces which you can use to indent a <pre> style code block
```

And the `backticks you can use to format code inline`, and also the automatic color syntax highlighting.

I believe the code highlighting is done via google's 'code prettify' but I'm not sure about the other formatting. It's just so easy!

How can I use this formatting on my blog?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe StackOverflow uses [pagedown](http://code.google.com/p/pagedown/).  The [documentation](http://code.google.com/p/pagedown/wiki/PageDown) seems to sum it up pretty well with examples, including a [demo](http://pagedown.googlecode.com/hg/demo/browser/demo.html).